# How can I find out how many triangles are in my model?

Tags: mesh, interface, objects

When I want to make some item, e.g. for a game, there's big chance for some triangle limit.
Is there some way how to find out how many triangles are in my model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select your object, and go into edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). In the info bar it will say how many triangles are in your object.

[image]

In object mode it will tell you how many triangles you have in the current layer(s).

Comment: In Blender 2.9+ you might need to right click the bottom bar and enable "Scene Statistics" to see this info.